# Multiple :before or :after pseudo-elements in css

Tags: html, css

Let us say that i have a div that holds the notification messages like

```
<div class="notification"></div>
```

The message is generated dynamically through PHP like

```
<div class="notification><?php echo $notif;?></div>
```

But I want that div to say that it holds notification like

```
Notification: [notification message]
```

So I put in css:

```
.notification:before{
    content:'Notification: ';
}
```

The problem is can I put another content just for that div. for example I want a warning picture to appear before **Notification:**

So can put another before and

```
.notification:before{
     content:url(warning.png);
}
```

If i do like that the last one comes. So how can I show both of them?

Comment: why not `.notification{ background-image:url(warning.png) }` ? and also why not `<div class="notification>Notification: <?php echo $notif;?></div>` ?

Comment: If you arent using `:after`...why not use it for the image?

Comment: but **after** comes after the div has ended. right?

Comment: @BlaiseM. you can place the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements anywhere you want, just like normal elements, by using `position`. In this particular case, using only `::before` is the better solution though.

Answer (score 6):

You could set the image as a background to the `:before`, like this:

```
.notification:before {
    content: 'Notification: ';
    padding-left: 20px;
    background: url('warning.png') left center no-repeat;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fr6c6j3j/)

Comment: It seems to work. So what does the other attributes mean? left center?

Comment: It's the horizontal and vertical position of the background image.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you